# Converting a c++ unordered_map to java hashMap before returning it to java using JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, hashmap, java-native-interface

I have a very large c++ `unordered_map` on android platform I would like to return this as a hashMap in java using JNI.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_quantum_QUANTUM_getMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jdoubleArray bbox) {

    unordered_map<int, Foo> Map;
    Map = getData(filename, bbox);

    // convert Map to java object
    // return java object
}
```

I am quite new to JNI. I haven't found any helpful material on how to do this.

I tried the approach in the link below but I am getting a lot of compilation errors on this.

[how to correctly send a std::map<> from C++ to Java through JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460349/how-to-correctly-send-a-stdmap-from-c-to-java-through-jni)

Another suggestions was to pass an empty javaHashmap over JNI and populate it. But I am not sure on how to do that. what is the better solution?

Comment: In general, you will want to learn how to take any Java class, not just hashmap, and be able to call their methods from C++.  Good JNI books / documentation explains how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It will require some tweaking. You can do it by creating `Map` object inside `C++` or by passing `Map` from `Java` to `C++` and filling it there.

Basically, what you need is to:

1. create `HashMap`

```
  jclass mapClass = env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");
  if(mapClass == NULL) {
    return NULL;                  // alternatively, throw exception (recipeNo019)
  }

  jobject hashMap = env->NewObject(mapClass, mapConstructorID);
  if(hashMap == NULL) {
    return NULL;                  // as above
  }
```

2. making sure to embed your primitive types inside object (e.g. you can embed `int` inside `Integer`)

```
  jclass integerClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
  if(integerClass == NULL) {
    return NULL;                  // alternatively, throw exception (recipeNo019)
  }

  jmethodID integerConstructorID = env->GetMethodID(integerClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
  if(integerConstructorID == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  ...
  ...

  jobject key = env->NewObject(integerClass, integerConstructorID, pair.first);
```

3. filling `HashMap` with data

```
  for (auto const& pair: map) {
    jobject key = env->NewObject(integerClass, integerConstructorID, pair.first);
    jobject value = env->NewObject(integerClass, integerConstructorID, pair.second);
    if(key == NULL || value == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }
    env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, putMethodID, key, value);
  }
```

That's it. You can find full sample code here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo047
https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo048